# SSAS/ PowerBi / DAX - How to combine multiplie colunms in one

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas

I am using Power Bi with SSAS Tubular Model.

I have a table that causes duplication due to multiple managers on a project.

```
Projekt     Manager     Revenue 
Car-Sales   Bob        200k
Car-Sales   Chris      200k
Car-Sales   Tina       200k
```

I want to combine these Manager entries to one entry with commas.

```
Projekt     Manager            Revenue 
Car-Sales   Bob,Chris,Tina       200k
```

How do I write this in DAX?

Answer (score 0):

This should be done upstream in your data shaping stage but if you're stuck with DAX, then create a new table as follows:

[image]

```
Table 2 = ADDCOLUMNS( SUMMARIZE('Table', 'Table'[Projekt], 'Table'[Revenue]), "Manager", CONCATENATEX('Table', 'Table'[Manager], ","))
```